# Creating entry with eloquent - unexpected behavoiur

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to create an entry for a Contact:

```
Contact::create([
            'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
            'lastname' => $faker->lastName,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'location_id' => 6,
            'department_id' => 3
        ]);
```

In the model Contact.php:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'location_id',
    'department_id',
    'email'
];
```

The migration code:

```
Schema::create('contacts', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->integer('location_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('department_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

If I just try to create it with firstname, lastname, and email, it works fine. But for some reason it doesn't work with the location_id and department_id fields filled in. The entry doesn't appear in the db, but there is no error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "But for some reason it doesn't work" is not an error message.

Comment: I'm not getting an error message at all - it passes fine, but doesn't create the entry in the db. I've updated the submission.

Comment: Try running `DB::getQueryLog()` after that `create` call. See what it does.

Comment: That gives an empty array: `array(0) { }`

Answer (score -1):

Let's try this

```
// app/models/Location.php
class Location extends Eloquent { }

// app/models/Department.php
class Department extends Eloquent { }
```

and the migration to update

```
Schema::create('contacts', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('firstname');
    $table->string('lastname');
    $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('department_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```